# How to make stored procedure return empty result set if no user input is entered for parameter?

Tags: sql, parameters, procedure

I was wondering how I could write a stored procedure to where it returns a result set when a user inputs a value for specified parameter, but also that it will return an empty result set if the user executes the stored procedure without providing any value for the parameter.

For example I have this so far:

```
CREATE PROC Test (@input int)
AS
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column = @input
```

I'm not sure how I should go from here to put in the condition to where it checks if no user input is put in for the parameter, then return an empty result set. I was thinking an IF/ELSE statement and putting something like SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 0=1 or something like that.

Would anyone be able to show me the correct way in implementing this?

Thank you for any help

Comment: **@FaultString varchar(max) = null,**
Setting it null should return an empty result. It's probably not the most graceful way to handle it, but it all depends on how proper you'd like the solution to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE PROC Test (@input int = NULL)
AS
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column = ISNULL(@input,0) 
 -- provided that there is no 0 value otherwise -1
```